# Problemas para obtener el state de vuex desde el componente hijo durante el created o el computed actualizado sin problemas en el padre

Tags: vue.js, axios, vuex

Agradeciendo primero que nada el apoyo que me puedan brindar, les presento mi problema con la esperanza de que puedan ayudarme con su solución.

Tengo el siguiente archivo identificado como settings.js donde tengo los siguiente:

```
import axios from 'axios'
import * as types from '../mutation-types'

// state
export const state = {
  workteamData: null,
  workteamDataStatus: null
}

// getters
export const getters = {
    workteamData:  state => state.workteamData,
    workteamDataStatus:  state => state.workteamDataStatus

}

// mutations
export const mutations = {
  [types.FETCH_WORKTEAM] (state, { value }) {
    state.workteamData = value
  },
  [types.FETCH_WORKTEAM_STATUS] (state, { status }) {
    state.workteamDataStatus = status
  },

}

// actions
export const actions = {
  async fetchWorkteamData ({ commit }, payload) {
    try {
      const { data } = await axios.get('api/settings', payload)
      commit(types.FETCH_WORKTEAM, { value: data })
      commit(types.FETCH_WORKTEAM_STATUS, {  status: 'success' })
    } catch (e) {
      commit(types.FETCH_WORKTEAM_STATUS, { status: 'error' })
    }
  },
 
}
```

Tengo un componente Padre con donde entre otras se ejecuta la siguiente:

```
  created(){
    this.fetchWorkteamData(this.user.id)
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters({
        workteamData: 'settings/workteamData'
        }),
  },
  methods: {
            fetchWorkteamData(userId){
              this.$store.dispatch('settings/fetchWorkteamData', {  
                params: {
                  member_user_id: userId
                }
              })
            },
  },
```

En este punto, cuando ejecuto el código, puedo apreciar con la ayuda de la DevTools de Vue.js que el valor de la propiedad "workteamData" en el state, se actualiza como se esperaba.

En un componente Hijo, tengo lo siguiente:

```
mounted() { 
    // En este hook los computed deberían estar disponibles
    this.fetchData()     
},
computed: {
//Esto debería ser igual que usar mapGetters...
  userInfo(){
    return this.$store.getters['auth/user']
  },
  workTeamInfo(){
    return this.$store.getters['settings/workteamData']
  },
},
methods: {
  fetchData() {

      axios
          .get('api/mainform/requests'
          ,{
            params: {
              userId: this.userInfo.id,
              userRoles: this.workTeamInfo.userRoles
            }
          }
          )
          .then(response => {
            this.items = response.data.appraisal_requests
          });      
  },
```

Sin embargo, al ejecutar el código se me presenta el error

> Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: this.workTeamInfo is null"

Al revisar la DevTools, me percato que el valor que se presenta, no es el mismo que el del componente padre, si no que se corresponde a un momento o instancia del estado anterior. Es decir, el valor que tenia el state en el componente Padre antes de su última actualización.

Entiendo que vuex es reactivo y que en el hook mounted los computed ya esta disponibles.

Es importante tener en cuenta que en el componente hijo, solo requiero los valores actuales para esa propiedad del state, no la estoy actualizando, solo consultando.

A que puede deberse todo esto, que estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: si fetchdata solo se ejecuta en el mounted, en que momento esperas tener un valor, de algo que se ejecuta asincronicamente?

Comment: Entiendo, gracias por el apoyo, es posible usar async/await para esto? De ser así sería la solución del error en el mounted Hook. Reviso y te comento. De funcionar quedaría por resolver lo del getters para el valor del state workteamData

Comment: no termino de entender tu arquitectura, de porque piden datos el padre y el hijo, sobre todo el hijo en el mounted, que bien podrian venir desde el padre, asi que no se que decirte...

Comment: Este hijo es solo un primer componente donde requiero consultar el valor de esa propiedad del state. Hay otros componentes (hermanos, nietos, bisnietos, etc) donde requiero de acuerdo a los resultados del state condicionar el comportamiento de la aplicación.

Comment: Pero todo eso no deberia ser calculado por el state?... no puedo darte una respuesta, ya que no te entiendo... igual a esta pregunta, la respuesta es que esta mal, porque donde estas ejecutando el valor puede no existir...

Comment: Pero la idea de vuex, no es poder tener una variable administrada en un solo lugar (store) que puede ser consultada por cualquier componente. Entendiendo que eso es así, el problema se debe a que no se puede obtener el valor de una propiedad del state en el hook del mount?

Comment: Si si... eso es vuex.. y si, podes obtener un valor en el mounted.. Ahora, si la variable te da null, y luego cambia su valor, es porque al momento que la estas buscando es null... Entonces, en realidad, eso que haces vos en tu hijo, deberia estar en vuex, en algun lugar luego de que cargaste el valor anterior, y devolver el valor que vos queres. Yo usualmente cuando uso vuex, los componentes no tienen llamadas al back, todo se hace dentro de acciones de vuex. De esa forma, si tengo que cambiar mas de una cosa, encadeno las acciones, y solo devuelvo valores del estado...

Comment: si queres, lo charlamos en el [chat]

Comment: ok, te lo agradezco un montón, sigo el enlace del chat

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122941/room-for-oswaldog-and-gbianchi

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122942/discussion-between-oswaldog-and-gbianchi).